# Command to find out which machines I share a network with

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, networking, ip

Can I find out which other machines (their IPs) are on my network via Ubuntu command line? What I currently do is install Wireshark and monitor the traffic. Was just hoping there was a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: I think http://superuser.com might be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [nmap](http://nmap.org), and point it at your IP block. See [nmap-host discovery](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html).